# Cannot Query Feature Attributes from ArcGIS Online Feature Service

Tags: swift, gis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-online

I have created a feature service on ArcGIS online which has approximately 2000 features.  Each feature has four fields: name, latitude, longitude and a boolean validation field (true/false).  Two custom symbols are used - one for validated features and one for non-validated features.
I have successfully connected to the feature service from my native (xcode/swift) iOS application and the features are displayed properly on top of the basemap.
I have implemented a touch delegate and successfully detect when a feature symbol is tapped.  The issue I am having is trying to query (read) the "name" field attribute associated with the symbol that was tapped.  I have tried using the code below but have not been able to read the attribute:

```
 func geoView(_ geoView: AGSGeoView, didTapAtScreenPoint screenPoint: CGPoint, mapPoint: AGSPoint) {

    if let activeSelectionQuery = activeSelectionQuery {
        activeSelectionQuery.cancel()
    }
    guard let featureLayer = featureLayer else {
        return
    }
    //tolerance level
    let toleranceInPoints: Double = 12
    //use tolerance to compute the envelope for query
    let toleranceInMapUnits = toleranceInPoints * viewMap.unitsPerPoint
    let envelope = AGSEnvelope(xMin: mapPoint.x - toleranceInMapUnits,
                               yMin: mapPoint.y - toleranceInMapUnits,
                               xMax: mapPoint.x + toleranceInMapUnits,
                               yMax: mapPoint.y + toleranceInMapUnits,
                               spatialReference: viewMap.map?.spatialReference)

    //create query parameters object
    let queryParams = AGSQueryParameters()
    queryParams.geometry = envelope


    //run the selection query
    activeSelectionQuery = featureLayer.selectFeatures(withQuery: queryParams, mode: .new) { [weak self] (queryResult: AGSFeatureQueryResult?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: ",error)
        }
        if let result = queryResult {
            print("\(result.featureEnumerator().allObjects.count) feature(s) selected")
            print("name: ", result.fields)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the ArGIS iOS 100.6 SDK.
Any help would be appreciated in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `featureLayer` selection methods merely update the map view display to visually highlight the features.

From the `featureLayer`, you should get the `featureTable` and then call `query()` on that. Note that there are two methods. A simple [`query()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_feature_table.html#a43d152517c6ee3fa582d2f741367b7bb) that gets minimal attributes back, or [an override on `AGSServiceFeatureTable`](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_service_feature_table.html#aaf46db4c80935a6477ed7efe78528c96) that allows you to specify that you want all fields back. You might need to specify [`.loadAll`](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/_a_g_s_enumerations_8h.html#a8759867c0f22569d0f8fe103543bc199) on that override to get the `name` field back. We do it this way to avoid downloading too much information (by default we download enough to symbolize and label the feature).